# How to show a UIPickerVIew on click of a UIbutton

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollView` in which I have several `UIViews` as subviews. In one of the `UIView` I need to create an `UIButton`, on click of which, a `UIPickerView` should appear and if I can make the button the first responder then by the default action of the `UIScrollView`, it will scroll up to make place for the `UIPickerView`... is there any way I can accomplish this? Would I need to subclass `UIControl`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
-(void)btnAction{
UITextView* uitextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
uitextView.inputView = thePickerView;
[self.view addSubview:uitextView];

[uitextView becomeFirstResponder];}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is button adding, in this case directly in the _scrollView, you can easy change that.

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];

// button customization

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(showPickerView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_scrollView addSubview:btn];
[btn release]; // if non-ARC
```

After that you need to implement the `showPickerView:` method

```
- (void)showPickerView:(UIButton*)sender
{
    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    picker.tag = 998998;

    // picker customization..

    [self.view insertSubview:picker aboveSubview:_scrollView];
    [picker release]; // if non-ARC
}
```

Important part here is when close/done button is fired from the picker view you must hide the picker the most easy way which comes to my minds is

```
if([self.view viewWithTag:998998] != nil) {
    [[self.view viewWithTag:998998] removeFromSuperview]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the UIPickerView to cell.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; within a subclassed (well whatever you want to have the picker appear when tapped). Then over ride the inputView method for that class and return the UIPickerView within that method. That method sets a custom input view to display when the object becomes the first responder. It will animate everything for you like the keyboard. To have the scrollview scroll up, you'll want to handle this the same way you would for a keyboard (which is by setting the contentOffset for the scrollView). You can find this here: [apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html). It should be fairly straight forward from here as you have notifications to when the object resigns being first responder and becomes first responder. Just use those notifications ins tead of the keyboard notifications and use the default UIPickerView sizes instead of the keyboard.

```
    - (void)initalizeInputView {
    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}


- (UIView *)inputView {
        return self.picker;
}
```